# How do I supply different conditions based on a parameter in an IAM Role CloudFormation Template

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, openid-connect

I'm writing a CloudFormation template for an IAM role that I will assume through STS. I need to add a condition where a key equals a value, where both the key and value depends on a "Stage" parameter. The value I've been able to programmatically change depending on the parameter, but all my attempts to change the key based on Stage have failed.

I've tried both using a map and !FindInMap to get the correct key, as well as tried to construct a condition with both cases using !If.

In the first case...

```
Mappings:
  Constants:
    beta:
      Id: "beta.example.com"
      Endpoint: "beta-link.example.com/api/oauth2/v2:aud"
    prod:
      Id: "example.com"
      Endpoint: "link.example.com/api/oauth2/v2:aud"

AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
  Statement:
    Action:
      - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
    Condition:
      StringEquals:
        !FindInMap [Constants, !Ref Stage, Endpoint]:
          - !FindInMap [Constants, !Ref Stage, Id]
```

... I got an error: `map keys must be strings; received a map instead`

In the second case...

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
  Statement:
    Action:
      - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
    Condition:
      !If
        - !Equals [!Ref Stage, prod]
        - StringEquals:
          "link.example.com/api/oauth2/v2:aud": "example.com"
        - StringEquals:
          "beta-link.example.com/api/oauth2/v2:aud": "beta.example.com"
```

...I got another error: `Template format error: Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions`

In short, how can I specify a condition where both key and value depend on a parameter?

Answer (score 20):

I have struggled around 8 hours continuously and finally found an answer to this problem.
Just for the viewers I would like to summarise the problem:

**Problem Statement** : As a infrastructure engineer, I want to write a cloudformation resource for AWS::IAM::Role which defines a AssumeRolePolicyDocument with a Condition clause where the key needs to be parameterised. Also another question is can we use intrinsic functions with Condition keys?

**Answer**: Yes, it is possible using an out of the box style. **AssumeRolePolicyDocument** is a String Type as per the AWS Cloudformation [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-assumerolepolicydocument) for 'AWS::IAM::Role'. So instead of using YAML style data to the **AssumeRolePolicyDocument** property, just pass a raw JSON formatted Assumerole policy using **Fn::Sub** and use variables to replace the key without any issues or warnings. Below is an example that you can use. Its a complex use case that i was trying to solve but it shows how you can replace keys under a IAM Condition clause using !SUB,!Select etc.

```
  ExampleAppRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${Environment}-ExampleAppRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
                            Fn::Sub: 
                              - |
                                {
                                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                  "Statement": [
                                    {
                                      "Effect": "Allow",
                                      "Principal": {
                                        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/${id}"
                                      },
                                      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                                      "Condition": {
                                        "StringEquals": {
                                          "${clusterid}": "${serviceaccount}"
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              - 
                                clusterid: !Join ["",[!Sub "oidc.eks.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/id/",!Select [1, !Split ["//", !Select [0, !Split [".", !GetAtt Cluster.Endpoint]]]],":sub"]]
                                id: !Select [1, !Split ["//", !Select [0, !Split [".", !GetAtt Cluster.Endpoint]]]]
                                Region: !Sub ${AWS::Region}
                                serviceaccount: system:serviceaccount:default:awsiamroleexample
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref SnsPublishAccessPolicy
```

Let me know your thoughts in the comments section.

Comment: I am unable to get this strategy to work. I have the exact same use case, templating an EKS OIDC provider. It seems like using Lambdas and CustomResource is the more canonical way to do this. I appreciate your efforts. I have similarly spent 8+ hours trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me 8 hours of struggle.

Comment: Thank you! This helped immensely. The same can be done in json if you use the python cft_flip to flip the above to json - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip

Comment: This answer saved me hours! Kudos

Comment: This is a great answer and it works for me!!   Thank you for providing this amazing YAML code, it saves my time to figure out how to  create EKS service Account   :)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think using intrinsic functions within an IAM policy condition element is allowed, I haven't seen any example of that. Condition element only takes a set of predefined keys. I think you can try the following template, it's a bit verbose but it should work. Template powered by [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io)

```
  {  
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"Template created by CloudKast",
   "Parameters":{  

   },
   "Mappings":{  

   },
   "Conditions":{  
      "Prod":{  
         "Fn::Equals":[  
            {  
               "Ref":"Stage"
            },
            "prod"
         ]
      },
      "Dev":{  
         "Fn::Equals":[  
            {  
               "Ref":"Stage"
            },
            "dev"
         ]
      }
   },
   "Resources":{  
      "ProdRole":{  
         "Properties":{  
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{  
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[  
                  {  
                     "Sid":"Stmt1567153169873",
                     "Action":[  
                        "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
                     ],
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::namespace::relativeid"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "RoleName":"ProdRole"
         },
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Condition":"Prod"
      },
      "DevRole":{  
         "Properties":{  
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{  
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[  
                  {  
                     "Sid":"Stmt1567153169873",
                     "Action":[  
                        "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
                     ],
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::namespace::relativeid"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "RoleName":"DevRole"
         },
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role"
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{  

   }
}
```